# THREE.JS Place a plane along given line and an vector

Tags: vector, three.js, quaternions, normals, plane

I have an arbitrary line ins 3D space and perpendicular vector to it, so both could form a plane. See illustration.

[image]

The task is to place existed plane along this line, so plane's face
would be seen (rendered), see the second illustration.

[image]

Need a guide on how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Is this a homework assignment? (2) Please show your code and what you have tried.

Comment: No, I am too old for homework, but you right, gonna upload code soon.

Comment: @VVK: answered your question after looking into your website. Impressed.

Answer (score 5):

You may find working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Gangula/0s6nqL43/1/

The key point of the solution is to rotate plane by [.lookAt](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) having specifically defined vector .up, see how it works on my drawing.

[image: place plane along given line and an vector]

```js
// line is defined by p0-p1
var p0 = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 2, 1);
var p1 = new THREE.Vector3(2, -1, -1);

// any random point outside the line will define plane orientation
var p2 = p1.clone().add(new THREE.Vector3(0.4, 0.8, 0.53));

var material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
});

// draw the line for visual reference
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
geometry.vertices.push(
    p0,
    p1,
    p2
);
var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material2);
scene.add(line);

// get direction of line p0-p1
var direction = p1.clone().sub(p0).normalize();

// project p2 on line p0-p1
var line0 = new THREE.Line3(p0, p1);
var proj = new THREE.Vector3();
line0.closestPointToPoint(p2, true, proj);

// get plane side direction
var localUp = p2.clone().sub(proj).normalize();

// draw the projection, just nice to have
var axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(0.1);
axesHelper.position.copy(proj);
scene.add(axesHelper);

// calc plane normal vector (how we want plane to direct)
var n = new THREE.Vector3();
n.crossVectors(proj.clone().sub(p0), proj.clone().sub(p2));

// preparation is complete, create a plane now
const planeL = 2.15;
const planeW = 1.75;

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(planeL, planeW, 32);
var material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xa9cc00,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material3);

// now align the plane to the p0-p1 in direction p2
plane.position.copy(p0); //put plane by its center on p0
plane.up.copy(localUp); //adjust .up for future .lookAt call
plane.lookAt(p0.clone().add(n)); //rotate plane

// now just offset plane by half width and half height
plane.position.add(localUp.clone().multiplyScalar(planeW / 2));
plane.position.add(direction.clone().multiplyScalar(planeL / 2));

// done!
scene.add(plane);
```

Comment: Thanks for your great contribution.

Comment: I try the example code but nothing shows in browser, what need I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, controls;
var labelX, labelY, labelY;

var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json", function(font_) {

  init(font_);

});

function init(font_) {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(256, 512, 512);
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(0xDEDEDE, 1.0);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.enablePan = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;


  controls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE,
    RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT
  };

  var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
  });

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-196, 0, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(196, 0, 0));
  var xLine = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(xLine);

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, -196, 0));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 196, 0));
  var yLine = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(yLine);

  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -196));
  geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 196));
  var zLine = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
  scene.add(zLine);

  var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000
  });

  var textX = new THREE.TextGeometry("label_x", {

    font: font_,
    size: 6,
    height: 0.1,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: false,

  });

  labelX = new THREE.Mesh(textX, textMaterial);
  labelX.position.set(180, 0, -6);
  labelX.geometry.center();
  labelX.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2)
  scene.add(labelX);

  var textY = new THREE.TextGeometry("label_y", {

    font: font_,
    size: 6,
    height: 0.1,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: false,

  });

  labelY = new THREE.Mesh(textY, textMaterial);
  labelY.position.set(6, 180, 0);
  labelY.geometry.center();
  labelY.rotateZ(Math.PI / 2)
  scene.add(labelY);

  var textZ = new THREE.TextGeometry("label_z", {

    font: font_,
    size: 6,
    height: 0.1,
    curveSegments: 12,
    bevelEnabled: false,

  });

  labelZ = new THREE.Mesh(textZ, textMaterial);
  labelZ.position.set(-6, 0, -180);
  labelZ.geometry.center();
  labelZ.rotateY(Math.PI / 2)
  labelZ.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2)
  scene.add(labelZ);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

  animate();

}

function onWindowResize() {

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

}

function animate() {

  if (camera.position.y < 0) {

    labelX.rotation.set(Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    labelZ.rotation.set(0, Math.PI / 2, 0);
    labelZ.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);


  } else {

    labelX.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0);
    labelZ.rotation.set(0, Math.PI / 2, 0);
    labelZ.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);

  }


  if (camera.position.z < 0) {

    labelY.rotation.set(0, -Math.PI, -Math.PI / 2);

  } else {

    labelY.rotation.set(0, 0, Math.PI / 2);

  }

  controls.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Actually, I was trying to do this.

Comment: I have somewhat working solution for this problem too, three.js linear dimensions with 2D html text labels on top - http://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/j35p1fw8/ The labels are precisely positioned and aligned. Additionally, dimensions are "jumping" to present most readable texts for current camera PoV.

Comment: Usually, for such cases, I am using canvas HUD on top.
http://vkuchinov.github.io/Interactive3DModel/

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gangula/z3u4ahvj/